# How do I traverse up out of shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a structure:

```
<div>
    #shadow-root
        <span>
```

How do I reference the `div` from the `span`?

`span.parentNode` is the `#shadow-root`, and `.parentNode` from that is `null`

Comment: That makes no sense: http://jsfiddle.net/9FzAM/

Comment: @Ian your example is the regular DOM; this question is about shadow-DOM (enable in chrome devtools.)

Comment: @Mathletics A ha! I seriously had no idea what they meant by "shadow dom" (the `#` made me think "id"), and somehow missed the "shadow-dom" and "polymer" tags. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Ian -- see http://jsfiddle.net/9FzAM/1/ for an updated demo that creates the correct structure

Comment: `shadowRoot.host` would give you the `<div>`. Likewise, `div.shadowRoot` would get you the div's shadow root.

Comment: @ebidel -- `.host`, thank you :)  If you make an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @ebidel Good call. You can see `host` and `parentNode` properties of the shadow root with `console.dir(child.parentNode);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `shadowRoot.host` to give you the `<div>`. Likewise, `div.shadowRoot` would get you the div's shadow root.

Answer (score 0):

First find shadowRoot host from the element `el.getRootNode().host` and then use `closest()`

```js
el.getRootNode().host.closest('div.my_div')
```